# How does an AngularJS directive interact with a Bootstrap clearfix class?

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a simple directive that replaces the directive tag with some template HTML. The HTML includes a `<div>` with a Bootstrap class of "clearfix" (i.e., `<div class="clearfix">`). When the `<div>` is part of the template HTML everything works fine; however, when the `<div>` surrounds the directive tag the template HTML is not rendered.

THIS WORKS:

```
<div class="panel-body">
  <pr-details pr="selectedPr"></pr-details>

  <!-- Additional unaffected content -->
</div>

return {
  restrict: 'E',
  replace: 'true',
  scope: {pr: '=' },
  template:
    "<div class='clearfix'>\n" +
    "  <div class='pull-right'>\n" +
    "    <!-- floated content -->\n" +
    "  </div>\n" +
    "  <div>\n" +
    "    <!-- non-floated content -->\n" +
    "  </div>\n" +
    "</div>\n"
};
```

THIS DOESN"T WORK:

```
<div class="panel-body">
  <div class="clearfix">
    <pr-details pr="selectedPr"></pr-details>
  </div>

  <!-- Additional unaffected content -->
</div>


return {
  restrict: 'E',
  replace: 'true',
  scope: {pr: '=' },
  template:
    "<div class='pull-right'>\n" +
    "  <!-- floated content -->\n" +
    "</div>\n" +
    "<div>\n" +
    "  <!-- non-floated content -->\n" +
    "</div>\n" +
};
```

The only thing I can figure out is that having the `<pr-details>` tag between the parent "clearfix" `<div>` and the the child "pull-right" `<div>` interferes with the parent-child relationship for the Bootstrap "clearfix" implementation.

Can anyone shed any light on this? Is there a way to get these two things to work together? I can make this work by refactoring the HTML a bit, but I'm curious about to do this for future use.

Comment: can you post the pull-right css definition? thx

Comment: Standard Bootstrap CSS:

Comment: .pull-left {float: left !important;}
    .pull-right {float: right !important;}